# Does CLISP have something like SBCL's sb-ext:*posix-argv*?

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl, clisp

I'd like to be able to access CLISP's argv from Lisp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that there is either `ext:argv` or `ext:*args*`, depending on your needs (from the [implementation notes](http://clisp.sourceforge.net/impnotes.html#argv)).

Comment: See also cl-launch, which has portable code to get command-line arguments on each CL implementation.

Comment: CLISP doesn't recognize ext:argv, and ext:*args* is _almost_ right. *args* doesn't include the script name. See http://speely.wordpress.com/2010/11/27/writing-scripts-with-common-lisp/ for a hack that approximates argv.

Comment: Note that EXT:ARGV is a function, not a variable.

Comment: @Matthias Thanks, that difference regularly trips me up in Lisps. newLISP does the same thing.